# Node.JS: How to get the server's port from an external app?

Tags: ruby, node.js, port

I'm developing a Ruby app that communicate with Node.JS app and I want to know if there is a way to get the port used by the Node's app in my Ruby app.

If not, can you force to run on a choosen port, without changing the code in the Node's app ?

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840879/nodejs-how-to-get-the-servers-port), but it is in JS.

Cheers !

EDIT: This is possible with -p port

Comment: Is your Node.js app using Express? Bare HTTP? Opening a UDP port? Let's see some code. What you're asking for is pretty straightforward, you'd just pass the port to the Node app via command line.

Comment: I want to cover every case. I'm the one doing node app, I want to be able to host node app. What is the option in the command line ? Something like --port=8080 for example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [environment variable](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) to provide the port number to application. Or give it as a command line parameter.

Comment: I don't really understand how you do this, either way … Could you explain me ? The command line seems to be relevant in my case.