# How to get a Connect server's host name and port number?

Tags: javascript, node.js, port, node.js-connect

Similar to [this question for Express](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4840879), is there a programmatic way to get the host name and port number of a running [Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) server?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you actually mean? Are talking how do you determine that within your own code of your own connect server or are you talking about how you determine that in some already running application. Do you want to know that in the context of a request? etc, etc, etc

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

```
var http = require('http');
var connect = require('connect');
var app = connect().use(connect.static(__dirname)); //or any other use
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port, host, callback);
```

- [read more](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
var connect = require("connect");
var server = require("http").createServer(connect());
server.listen(function() {
  console.log(server.address()); // Print host name and port number.
});
```