# Get server's port from Node JS connect.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, port, connect.js

I'd like to output a message like "Listening on port {port_#}" to the terminal from my node js server.

I found documentation, such as this, [NodeJS: How to get the server's port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840879/nodejs-how-to-get-the-servers-port), but they only talk about Express JS.

I'm using the ConnectJS aspect to connect. So my code looks like:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(8080);

console.log("Listening on port %d", connect.address().port);
```

This, however, does not work. How would I log the port to terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call the `.address()` method of the connect library. This method does not exist. It does not even exist on an instance of `connect()`. The method you are looking for lives in the `http.Server` object.

When you create a connect instance, an app is returned. When you tell the app to listen, you can provide a callback which get called when the app begins to listen. This callback gets called with the `http.Server` as the context bound to `this`.

```
var connect = require( 'connect' )
var app = connect()
app.listen( 8080, function(){
  //`this` is the underlying http.Server powering the connect app
  console.log( 'App is listening on port ' + this.address().port )
})
```

From the [source code](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/45fe02dde8b1f1da0dde0c593038753714f1d99b/lib/proto.js#L186-L189) for connect:

```
app.listen = function(){
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```