# how to get the port number from the service name using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

We are developing a WebSocket server using Nodejs with socket.io

I have used createServer method from class HTTP and then listen to a port as follows :

```
var server = http.createServer();
  server.listen(port, function () {
  ...
}
```

Now The problem is that I only have the service name 
and  listening to a service doesn't work :

```
var server = http.createServer();
  server.listen(service, function () {
  ...
}
```

So I need to read and parse the file /etc/services to get the port associated with the service as follows :

```
var str = fs.readFileSync(filename).toString();
var serviceline = str.match( port+".*tcp" );
var port = serviceline[0].match( "[0-9]+" )
```

Is there a simpler way to get the port from the service?

Thanks in advance

Jean-Marie

Comment: Try with this :
console.log('Listening on port ' + server.address().port);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS: How to get the server's port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840879/nodejs-how-to-get-the-servers-port)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [find-process](https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-process) to find port from process or vice-versa

**Command line usage**

`npm install find-process -g`

```
Usage: find-process [options] <keyword>


Options:

    -V, --version      output the version number
    -t, --type <type>  find process by keyword type (pid|port|name)
    -p, --port         find process by port
    -h, --help         output usage information

Examples:

    $ find-process node          # find by name "node"
    $ find-process 111           # find by pid "111"
    $ find-process -p 80         # find by port "80"
    $ find-process -t port 80    # find by port "80"
```

**Code usage**

`npm install find-process --save`

```
const find = require('find-process');

find('pid', 12345)
  .then(function (list) {
    console.log(list);
  }, function (err) {
    console.log(err.stack || err);
  })
```

I have used this to find process from the port but I think it provides a reverse way to or you can skim down to its repo and pick the code you needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't need a server port but the port corresponding to a service name
for instance having the following service "wsgw" specified in file /etc/services

```
wsgw      8001/tcp               # websocket gateway
```

I need to get the value 8001 before running the server listening to this port this way :

```
var server = http.createServer();
server.listen(8001, function () {
...
```

listening to a service as below doesn't work :

```
var server = http.createServer();
server.listen("wsgw", function () {
...
```

note : finding a port from a process doesn't help me as it is not a process but a service